# Comparing CSVs with rows as multiples of 6

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files with rows as n-multiples of 6 and I want to compare them. If a row in CSV1 has the same values of column 1 to 3 as any in CSV2, but their column 4 values are different replace the column 4 in CSV1 with column 4 in CSV2. So far I have written the code below which reads both CSVs and groups them by 6(s) but I don't know what next to do as it results in a list of list of list which I cannot handle. N.B One CSV has more rows than the other.

My Code:

```
import csv

def datareader(datafile):

    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:

        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader, None)
        List1 = [lines for lines in reader]

    return [List1[pos:pos + 6] for pos in xrange(0, len(List1), 6)]

list1 = datareader('CSV1.csv')


def datareader1(datafile):

    # Read the csv
    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:

        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader, None)
        List2 = [lines for lines in reader]

    return [List2[pos:pos + 6] for pos in xrange(0, len(List2), 6)]

list2 = datareader1('CSV2.csv')
```

CSV1

```
frm to  grp dur
192 177 1   999999
192 177 2   749
192 177 3   895
192 177 4   749
192 177 5   749
192 177 6   222222
192 178 1   222222
192 178 2   222222
192 178 3   222222
192 178 4   222222
192 178 5   1511
192 178 6   999999
192 179 1   999999
192 179 2   387
192 179 3   969
192 179 4   387
192 179 5   387
192 179 6   999999
```

CSV2

```
from_BAKCode    to_BAKCode  interval    duration
192 177 1   999999
192 177 2   749
192 177 3   749
192 177 4   749
192 177 5   749
192 177 6   999999
192 178 1   999999
192 178 2   999999
192 178 3   999999
192 178 4   999999
192 178 5   1511
192 178 6   999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas module to deal with data manipulation. It will be much easier.

```
import pandas as pd

def add_new_dur(row):
    if row['dur'] == row['duration']: return row['dur']
    else: return row['duration']

fileNameCSV1 = 'csv1.csv'
fileNameCSV2 = 'csv2.csv'

df = dict()
for f in [fileNameCSV1, fileNameCSV2]:
    df[f.split('.')[0]] = pd.read_csv(f)

result = df['csv1'].merge(df['csv2'],
                          left_on = ['frm', 'to', 'grp'],
                          right_on = ['from_BAKCode', 'to_BAKCode', 'interval'])

result['new_dur'] = result.apply(add_new_dur, axis=1)

result = result[['frm', 'to', 'grp', 'new_dur']]

result = result.rename(columns={'new_dur':'dur'})
```

The result will look like this.

```
    frm to  grp dur
0   192 177 1   999999
1   192 177 2   749
2   192 177 3   749
3   192 177 4   749
4   192 177 5   749
5   192 177 6   999999
6   192 178 1   999999
7   192 178 2   999999
8   192 178 3   999999
9   192 178 4   999999
10  192 178 5   1511
11  192 178 6   999999
```

Incase you have one csv file has greater number of rows than the other csv file, then the extra rows will be omitted.

Hope it helps.